# ¿Cómo seguir ejecutando script.sql cuando ocurre un error?

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin

¿Es posible continuar con la ejecución de un script SQL al encontrar un error? Por ejemplo, si la columna es `not null` y se le asigna valor `null`, ¿es posible continuar con la ejecución? Y si es posible, ¿qué comando debería ejecutar?

```
CREATE TABLE usuarios (
    id_usu SERIAL,
    nom_usu VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    log_usu VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    pas_usu VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    niv_adm BOOLEAN,
    PRIMARY KEY(id_usu)
);
```

Allí tenemos la tabla con valores `NOT NULL`. Si volcamos datos en ella y los valores son `null` no se seguirá ejecutando la consulta.

```
INSERT INTO usuarios (nom_usu, log_usu, pas_usu, niv_adm) VALUES (null, 'ADD', 'XXXXX', 1);
INSERT INTO usuarios (nom_usu, log_usu, pas_usu, niv_adm) VALUES ('CHRIS', 'ADD', 'XXXXX', 1);
```

Y el segundo `INSERT` no procederá a volcar sus datos que son del tipo correcto.

Comment: ¿Para que la pregunta sea mas clara, puedes proveer un pequeño script que ilustra lo que estás pidiendo? También, ¿qué estás usando para ejecutar el script?

Comment: ¿qué programa cliente estás usando para ejecutar el script?

Comment: pgadmin III como me recomiendas que lo haga?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En PgAdmin, puedes ejecutar el script usando la opción en el menú `Query --> Execute pgScript`. O puedes usar `F6`.

En ambos casos, el script debería ejecutarse por completo, aún si ocurren ciertos errores.

Otra opción es de ejecutar el script usando el programa **psql** en vez de PgAdmin. El comportamiento por defecto de **psql** es de continuar ejecutando cuando ocurre un error. Puedes usar el comando siguiente para ejecutar el script:

```
\i c:/path/script.sql
```

Comment: Como lo ejecuto en windows

Comment: ¿Probastes con F6 en PgAdmin? ¿No te funcionó?

Comment: psql retorna esto 
postgres-# \i script.sql
psql:script.sql:2: ERROR:  el valor null para la columna «nom_usu» viola la restricción not null
DETALLE:  La fila que falla contiene (7, null, ADD, XXXXX, t).

Comment: Aunque te dió el error, el script debe haber continuado. Si verificas en la tabla, deberías ver que los demás inserts funcionaron. ¿no?

Comment: Si funciono!!! gracias !!!